dotnet maui not able to trigger simulator ios
on my windows 10 I have Maui application using visual studio 2022 version 17.11.5
on MacBook I have Sequoia 15.1 and  Xcode 16.0
it paired to mac successfully but when I tried to build using iPhone 15 iOS 17.5 or
iPhone 15 18.0 I get error message
Error (active)      clang++ exited with code 1:

ld: building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file
(/Users/sam/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/CompanyMobile/94ebe42756bc16592cb442b5ab77d43d079a57dfde5e720b972b8ef1e104efc6/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/linker-cache/AppCenter.a[arm64][2](MSACAppCenter.o))
built for 'iOS'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)   CompanyMobile(net8.0-ios)   C:\Program
Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0\18.0.8303\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets   1643

I found out that this package causing the error above
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="5.0.4" />



<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'"> <ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>true</ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE> </PropertyGroup>



I added ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE but didn't work as mentioned in one of the discussion.
any help would be appreciated.

Several things are working against you:



AppCenter is scheduled to be retired in March 31, 2025.




AppCenter doesn't ship support for iossimulator-arm64



This means, all you have is:

Find an older Intel base mac (non Apple Silicon) to do your iOS Simulator testing, Or
Only test on iOS Device not iOS Simulator

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/retirement
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/issues/1755
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16778

